# Mockito Test Case for Jdbc template and Spring's keyHolder

Tags: spring, mockito, jdbctemplate, springmockito

I wrote a test case but I get a null pointer exception at the `return KeyHolder.getKey()` line.

My test case looks like this:

```
@InjectMocks
private UserDAOImpl userDAO;

@Mock
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Mock
private KeyHolderFactory keyHolderFactory;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(userDAO, "jdbcTemplate", jdbcTemplate);
}

@Test
public void testCreateUser() {

    KeyHolder keyHolder = mock(GeneratedKeyHolder.class);

    when(keyHolderFactory.newKeyHolder()).thenReturn(keyHolder);

    User user = getUserInfo();

    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("id",1L);
    when(keyHolder.getKeys()).thenReturn(map);
    when(keyHolder.getKey()).thenReturn(1L);

    when(jdbcTemplate.update(Mockito.any(PreparedStatementCreator.class), Mockito.any(KeyHolder.class))).thenReturn(1);

    assertEquals(1L, userDAO.createUser(user));
}
```

And the method looks like this:

```
 @Override
  public long createUser(User user) {

KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

jdbcTemplate.update(connection -> {
  PreparedStatement ps = connection
      .prepareStatement("insert into user (address, first_name,last_name, email, password, phone_number, is_init, is_system_admin, created_at)"
              + " values( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)",
          Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
  ps.setString(1, user.getAddress());
  ps.setString(2, user.getFirstName());
  ps.setString(3, user.getLastName());
  ps.setString(4, user.getEmail());
  ps.setString(5, user.getPassword());
  ps.setString(6, user.getPhone());
  ps.setBoolean(7, user.isActive());
  ps.setBoolean(8, user.isSystemAdmin());
  ps.setDate(9, new Date(Date.from((user.getCreatedAt().toInstant())).getTime()));

  return ps;
}, keyHolder);

return (long) keyHolder.getKey();
  }
```

I have created an interface `KeyHolderFactory`:

```
public interface KeyHolderFactory {
KeyHolder newKeyHolder();
}
```

And the implementation of this interface is as follows:

```
public class GeneratedKeyHolderFactory implements KeyHolderFactory {

public KeyHolder newKeyHolder() {
    return new GeneratedKeyHolder();
  }
}
```

Can someone help me to find a solution?

Comment: Why? Why do you want to test the Spring Framework (because that is what you are essentially doing here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is next :

In test class you have Mocked bin `KeyHolderFactory` and this is correct. Then you create mocked `KeyHolder`, describe it's behavior and make `KeyHolderFactory` return `KeyHolder` when it is asked. Everything looks OK except next :

On your code class method you create new `KeyHolder` using `new GeneratedKeyHolder()` and this new `KeyHolder` doesn't relate to those mocked instance that you have in your test class. It is absolutely different objects. That one which is in your test class - is a mock, and will follow your scenario. But that one, in your tested class method, is another object, which of course don't know what to do when you execute `keyHolder.getKey()`.

Solution :

You have injected `KeyHolderFactory` in your test and well configured it's behavior. Just inject this into your test class as well and use it in your method to create `KeyHolder` using `keyHolderFactory.newKeyHolder()` instead of `new GeneratedKeyHolder()`

Comment: This Solution Worked For me ,Thank you @AndriyRymar